# Dayjs isBetween for Time String

Tags: dayjs

I have shift start and shift end times in time format like "18:00". I need to determine current time is between these times by using dayjs. I tried following logic but my shift start and shift end times can be "20:00 - 06:00". Because end time passes the other day following logic doesn't work.. How to do that in proper way

```
const shiftStart = this.$dayjs().hour(shift.shift_start.split(':')[0]).minute(shift.shift_start.split(':')[1])

const shiftEnd = this.$dayjs().hour(shift.shift_end.split(':')[0]).minute(shift.shift_end.split(':')[1])

return this.$dayjs().isBetween(shift_start, shift_end, 'hour')
```